# Can "yarn add global " update packages installed by npm?

Tags: npm, nativescript, yarnpkg

I use yarn as package-manager but the first time I install nativescript I used;

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

Can I update the package using `yarn add global nativescript`?

**NOTE:** I run `tns package-manager set yarn` in my projects folder

Comment: Yes, you could do that. It's just going to install fresh copy if none exists already Or just updates package. I guess the syntax should be `yarn global add nativescript`. Also you might have to update yarn path on bash profile.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ;

> yarn global add nativescript

and

```
yarn global upgrade
```

updates packages which are installed by **npm**

Please consider checking [migrating from npm](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/)

Thanks to @Manoj for answer